# Deploying two almost same applications on single tomcat instance

Tags: java, spring, unix, tomcat

I have an application which is deployed on tomcat and up and running. Tomcat is installed on an unix OS. And i want to deploy an other copy of the same application(with little code change, same application name) to the same tomcat instance to run on different port. Is it possible to run the same application with different port on same instance of tomcat. Is single tomcat instance running on single jvm?. If so then what are the issues will occur?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can deploy it by changing the port, there is no problem at all....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I heard like different application works fine with same instance, but same application will interfere with the other application because both are same code since they are running on same jvm. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'little code change', how little is that? If its only about a few items, then it can be easily handled by sending different request param values/hidden values/path variables such as following.

`/myapp/doSomething?pm=false` & `/myapp/doSomething?pm=true`

Wouldn't it be a pain to maintain 2 different instances where the difference is about only a very few functionalities?

Comment: Hi, The changes are in few items only. But the application is handled by other teams for thier assesment. we shouldn't disturb them. We got the environment information through client who agreed to do that.

Comment: You can easily restrict the access to certain items based on the users from team1/team2. Maintaining 2 different instances will be a pain. Any downtime will affect both teams anyway. So, I think, a little tweak in you code to restrict access will be much more easier and maintainable in the long run.